# Creating query with Option<T> as parameter

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, vavr

I'm trying to make a mongo query (using Spring Data) for searching record by the Option value from Vavr. I have value Option userId and I'm wondering if it's possible to search in database by this parameter.

I have serched in MongoDB and Spring documentation, but in none of this is anything about Vavr type like Option. None of this query are working.

```
Option<Result> FindFirstByUserIdAndCreationDateDesc(String userId);

Option<Result> FindFirstByOptionUserIdAndCreationDateDesc(String userId);
```

where userId is Vavr Option

```
Option<String> userId;
```

Answer (score 1):

Vavr's `Option` and Java's `Optional` are types for eliminating the `null` value.

Database don't use *optional* values, they use `null` values, so unwrap the value to a `null`.

```
userId.getOrElse(null)
```

However, be aware that in e.g. SQL databases, the `null` value doesn't compare equal to itself, so a `WHERE userId = ?` will return nothing if the `?` argument is `null`. To find records with a `null` value, the SQL must be `WHERE userId IS NULL`, so unless your `FindXxx` methods knows this and account for it, the code will still not work for you.

Comment: SQL treatment of null is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is in the saving objects in repository. If I save object with Option<T> value, for example class User, with Option<String> userId value, its impossible (probably) to make proper query to search in database by this userId.

Comment: @MateuszKwiecień If the value of `userId` in the database is an `Option<String>`, then of course you need to search the database using an `Option<String>`, not a `String`, because `Option<String>` and `String` are two different types. Which part of that is difficult to understand? I mean, if the value on the database was a `Long`, would you try to search using a `BigDecimal`? Of course not, because `Long` and `BigDecimal` will never compare equal. Neither will `Option<String>` and  `String`.